# Search and handle multiple matches in Excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to search for a string with multiple matches in my Excel document, basically its a summary of inventory transactions, so in my case I'm looking for string "Summa" (EN: sum) in cells E2:E3000, there are one sum for each article, so it will be about 500 matches. For every match I would like to paste a formula and a conditional format into the cell next to the sum. Is there someone who can help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Search & Replace feature from excel (open it via ctrl+f). Here you have to press on "options"; with this you can search for strings inside formulas.

For example search for =sum and replace with =sum'#yourString'.
You can also add conditional format to all replaced values. For this and the other above mentioned steps see the yellow highlights on the picture below.

[Find & Replace Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzOss.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, this is however not what I'm looking for. I want to use vba so it's an automated process since the cell values are going to change every month.